# Edit the DisplayName property of a FlowDecision in Rehosted Workflow Designer

Tags: c#, workflow-foundation, .net-4.5

I tried to to edit the `DisplayName` property of a `FlowDecision` activity in the **Rehosted Workflow Designer** mode but without success, neither in the properties panel I can't see it (*also in rehosted mode*).

In VS2012 it works perfectly, have you any idea if I can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I know, that this was like 4 years ago, anyway.. 
Main problem is that the display name is actually updated, but the UI holds other structure for workflow itself (ModelItem typed). So if you would safe that workflow of yours, it should have expected value (new display name).

So, you change Activity name, for example in ModelChanged event handling like this:
`args.ModelChangeInfo.Value.Properties[nameof(State.DisplayName)]?.SetValue("New Name")`